# Can I make Microsoft Office ignore Windows language settings?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, language, spell-check

Office seems to have its own language system, since there is a setting tab for it and you can set your default.

But I'm having great difficulty trying to make Outlook obey my settings.

Basically, I have my system (Windows 10) use English as my default language. This is the language I want to see in all applications and while browsing the web.

However, I live in Belgium, and so communication with colleagues happens mostly in Dutch. Although I have installed the language pack for Dutch in Office and set it to default, the spell checking that Outlook applies whenever I type an e-mail is based on whatever language is currently active in Windows. This means it **invariantly** starts with English spell checking although I am **invariantly** starting a Dutch e-mail. Auto-detection catches up after a few sentences, but before that it's already auto-correcting some stuff which is extremely annoying.

I have also set Dutch as a second language in Windows because I personally prefer QWERTY keyboard layout but occasionally need to switch to AZERTY in case a colleague needs to use my computer. I know the keyboard layout isn't necessarily tied to a language, but if I were to set Dutch as my primary language in Windows, suddenly many applications and sites try to please me by talking Dutch. I'm a developer here, English makes a lot more sense in most cases.

I wonder why it provides two ways to supposedly change your default language (Also under Review -> Language -> Set Proofing Language and then "Set as default"), when it doesn't make a difference anyway. Extremely frustrating UX.

So, the question is, **how can I make Office ignore the Windows primary language during spell checking?**

Comment: The language Office uses and the language Windows uaes are independent.  They both have language packs, Windows 10 language packs are free, depending on the version of Office the language packs are free.  Keyboard layout is also separate from the language pack.

Comment: @Ramhound then how do you explain that the proofing language in Outlook changes at the same time I change my Windows language? (Using the language menu next to the system clock)